# Errors when compiling a grammar

Tags: compilation, antlr, grammar

I have a grammar P.g that until recently compiled quietly. Today when I type in the command prompt:

**java -cp .;../antlr-3.5-complete.jar org.antlr.Tool P.g**

(the grammar is in the folder *gram*, while antlr-3.5-complete.jar is in the parent folder. The prompt is placed in the folder *gram*.)

Generates the following errors:

```
warning(24):  template error: context [/outputFile /parser /genericParser /region__/genericParser__m
embers] 32:3 no such property or can't access: org.antlr.tool.Grammar.indirectDelegates
Caused by: org.stringtemplate.v4.misc.STNoSuchPropertyException: no such property: org.antlr.tool.Gr
ammar.indirectDelegates
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.misc.ObjectModelAdaptor.throwNoSuchProperty(ObjectModelAdaptor.java
:106)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.misc.ObjectModelAdaptor.lookupMethod(ObjectModelAdaptor.java:99)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.misc.ObjectModelAdaptor.getProperty(ObjectModelAdaptor.java:67)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter.getObjectProperty(Interpreter.java:1158)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter._exec(Interpreter.java:210)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter.exec(Interpreter.java:145)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter.writeObject(Interpreter.java:703)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter.writeObjectNoOptions(Interpreter.java:635)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter._exec(Interpreter.java:285)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter.exec(Interpreter.java:145)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter.writeObject(Interpreter.java:703)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter.writeObjectNoOptions(Interpreter.java:635)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter._exec(Interpreter.java:285)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter.exec(Interpreter.java:145)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter.writeObject(Interpreter.java:703)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter.writeObjectNoOptions(Interpreter.java:635)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter._exec(Interpreter.java:285)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter.exec(Interpreter.java:145)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.ST.write(ST.java:415)
        at org.antlr.codegen.CodeGenerator.write(CodeGenerator.java:1296)
        at org.antlr.codegen.Target.genRecognizerFile(Target.java:98)
        at org.antlr.codegen.CodeGenerator.genRecognizer(CodeGenerator.java:459)
        at org.antlr.Tool.generateRecognizer(Tool.java:696)
        at org.antlr.Tool.process(Tool.java:509)
        at org.antlr.Tool.main(Tool.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.misc.Misc.invokeMethod(Misc.java:218)
        at org.stringtemplate.v4.misc.ObjectModelAdaptor.lookupMethod(ObjectModelAdaptor.java:84)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.removeAll(Unknown Source)
        at org.antlr.tool.CompositeGrammar.getIndirectDelegates(CompositeGrammar.java:226)
        at org.antlr.tool.Grammar.getIndirectDelegates(Grammar.java:2722)
        ... 29 more
```

I did not change anything. From what all of these errors are due?

thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens using Java8, try to switch back to 7

Comment: Why is this happening in java8?

Answer (score 4):

The latest version of antlr 3.5 doesn't have this problem (3.5.2)

Comment: It does on macOS Sierra... with antlr-3.5.2-complete.jar